# Is waiting a thread to be alive with a loop good practice?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Do we really have to do this?

`// Loop until worker thread activates.
while (!workerThread.IsAlive);`

Wouldn't it be better to just use a ManualResetEvent (or else) at the start of the thread's function?

**Edit 1:**

Perhaps in the MSDN example context it would be "appropiate":

`// Start the worker thread.
workerThread.Start();
Console.WriteLine("main thread: Starting worker thread...");
 
// Loop until worker thread activates.
while (!workerThread.IsAlive);`

Otherwise this just feels like an awful code smell.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/7a2f3ay4(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea enter to loop. You waste your CPU time - much beter use MRE.

Comment: @al_amanat still, wouldn't a loop as simple as this count as spinning?

Comment: Think about what would happen if you started the thread, and it exited just before you entered the while loop. Now consider if that loop would ever be a good idea.

Comment: @MatthewWatson then MSDN would have some explaining to do (?) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/7a2f3ay4(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @AStackOverflowUser There's plenty of examples of bad advice in MSDN; this is just one of many!

Comment: @Matthew Watson *readies virtual pitchforks*

Comment: @JeroenMostert that's the best answer so far. Feel free to add it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please ignore the MSDN example, it's horrible and senseless. In particular, the spin waiting on `IsAlive` makes no sense because there is no way for the thread to be terminated "before it has a chance to execute", as the MSDN says. The thread is free not to check the flag you set for requesting termination until it is ready. Spin-waiting on `IsAlive` never makes sense -- use `Thread.Join()` to wait on exit, and events (or monitors) to wait for other states.

Comment: TIL calling MSDN horrible and senseless will make you popular. To any reading this, please also read Dialecticus answer below as it is very similar but fairly completes the notion. 

I will choose this however, because it is more illustrative of the danger of spinning like this.

Comment: That's a bit harsh -- the MSDN contains a lot of pages with excellent information. The page you mentioned just happens to not be one of those.

Comment: Haha, don't worry @Jeroen. We completely understood your stance. It is a thing of this particular example here.

Answer (score 3):

Good practice is to use the [**Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175(v=vs.110).aspx)

Use [`Task.Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051(v=vs.110).aspx) like this,

```
public async Task DoStuff(CancellationToken token)
{
    await Task.Run(
        () => Console.WriteLine("Stuff"),
        token)
}
```

or just,

```
Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine("Stuff")).Wait();
```

Comment: let's assume, for the sake of argument, that you couldn't use TAP. What would you do then? What would be best practice in that case?

Comment: @AStackOverflowUser use `Thread.Join` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.join(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @AStackOverflowUser for the sake of argument, is there a good reason to not use TAP?

Comment: Join would block the running thread until it finishes. This implies waiting right away until it starts.

Comment: for the beautiful and joyous sake of reinventing the wheel sire.

Comment: @AStackOverflowUser "while continuing to perform standard COM and SendMessage pumping." A while loop won't do that, it will just eat CPU, in that past, when trying to handle cancellation a `Thread.Sleep()` may have been introduced. Handrolling or DIY multi-threading is fraught with pitfalls and should not be undertaken lightly.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in infrastructure to wait for thread to start, because in most cases this should not be important. We must wait for thread to finish always, but let it do about its business in the mean time.

You probably even don't want to wait for thread to start. You probably want for thread to activate some of its functionality, and in general case there could me more than one of those functionalities. No built-in system can cater for this, so you have to roll your own synchronization.

Just have some event that is created when the thread is created, but is raised in the thread run code. When you create and start the thread wait on this event and that's it.

Comment: That's actually what I did. Thanks Dialecticus for thinking alike.